# Mounting ISO with`fuseiso` produces different filenames than `mount`. How to change this behavior?

Tags: mount, filenames, iso

I need to mount an ISO as non-root. File names inside the mounted ISO matter. Since I'm "non-root", `fuseiso` is the most logical choice, but it doesn't produce "correct filenames", while `mount` does. With `fuseiso`, spaces are replaced with underscores, and capital letters are uncapitalized.

Is there a way to change `fuseiso`'s behavior to copy that of `mount` ?

Correct content of the ISO with mount:

```
[me@pc stalkersoup]$ sudo mount 'STALKERSOUP Game Install.iso' mnt 
[me@pc stalkersoup]$ ls mnt
'STALKERSOUP game setup-10.bin'  'STALKERSOUP game setup-4.bin'  'STALKERSOUP game setup-8.bin'
'STALKERSOUP game setup-1.bin'   'STALKERSOUP game setup-5.bin'  'STALKERSOUP game setup-9.bin'
'STALKERSOUP game setup-2.bin'   'STALKERSOUP game setup-6.bin'  'STALKERSOUP game setup.exe'
'STALKERSOUP game setup-3.bin'   'STALKERSOUP game setup-7.bin'
```

Incorrect content of the ISO with `fuseiso`:

```
[me@pc stalkersoup]$ fuseiso 'STALKERSOUP Game Install.iso' mnt/
[me@pc stalkersoup]$ ls mnt/
stalkersoup_game_setup_10.bin  stalkersoup_game_setup_4.bin  stalkersoup_game_setup_8.bin
stalkersoup_game_setup_1.bin   stalkersoup_game_setup_5.bin  stalkersoup_game_setup_9.bin
stalkersoup_game_setup_2.bin   stalkersoup_game_setup_6.bin  stalkersoup_game_setup.exe
stalkersoup_game_setup_3.bin   stalkersoup_game_setup_7.bin
```

Context, to avoid a XYZ problem situation:

- File name matters, because I want to extract the content of `setup.exe` with innoextract, and all the `bin` files contain data required for extraction, and their path is hard-coded
- I do this because I'm writing a PKGBUILD (a bash script for building packages for arch). This is a bash script that must run as non-root. Therefore, I'm restricted to CLI tools as non-root
- I do this for my personal usage, and this is legal as the game is freely distributed
- Renaming is not an option, since mounted ISO is read-only
- I can extract the content of the ISO with p7zip for instance, which is what I'm currently doing
- This is not a good solution though, because it wastes time and storage
- I can't modify the archive, as I must use it "as published by the author"

Thanks in advance for your help and expertise :)

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer with the help of reddit. I'll summarize here, but you can refer to [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/jvyi09/fuseiso_produces_different_filenames_than_mount/).

Option 1: with guestmount

```
guestmount -a 'STALKERSOUP Game Install.iso' -m /dev/sda mnt/
```

Where you find /dev/sda with :

```
virt-filesystems -a "STALKERSOUP Game Install.iso"
```

Option 2: with udisks

```
# Setup loop file with udisksctl 
udisksctl loop-setup --file "STALKERSOUP Game Install.iso"
bdev="/dev/loop0"                          # can change
udisksctl mount --block-device "$bdev" 
mpoint="/media/STALKERSOUP Game Install"   # can change
```